# How to compute a minimal half-space representation?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, polytopes

I have a convex polytope given as half-space representation

$$ A x \leq b $$

with matrix $A \in R^{M \times N}$,
vector $x \in R^{N}$,
vector $b \in R^{M}$
and $M>N$.

**My question is:** 
How can I efficiently compute a *minimal half-space representation* (without computing the vertex-representation)?

In other words, I want to reformulate the above inequality without modifying the corresponding polytope in order to obtain

$$ A^{*} x \leq b^{*}$$

where $A^{*}$ and $b^{*}$ have the minimum number of required rows (less rows compared to the original $A$ and $b$).

Or, in other words, I want to get rid of halfplanes in $A$ that do not intersect with the polytope.

Comment: Denote the remainder by $A' x \le b'$. Then each row of $A'x \le b'$ can be expressed as non-negative linear combination of rows of $A^\ast x \le b^\ast$, right?

Comment: You are right. However, given that there are (for example three) rows that linearly depend on each other: How shall I select which one to remove?

Comment: It seems it is the problem of finding minimal descriptions of polyhedra, see: https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/~ted/files/ie418/lectures/Lecture5.pdf, and http://karthik.ise.illinois.edu/courses/ie511/lectures-sp-19/5.pdf